# jQuery find all inputs outside the form block

Tags: jquery

How to find all input elements that are **outside** the form block, using jQuery?

Comment: It is 'jQuery', not 'jquery' or 'JQuery' or 'Jquery'.

Comment: In a tag it's 'jquery' :) The question is still actual

Comment: Any chance you could update your markup so that the inputs you need are in their own container? Either that or they have a specific class? Otherwise, even though there's ways to do this (as per the answers folks have posted already), that'll be worse, performance-wise, than just doing $('input.someclass');

Comment: I can't change HTML. It would be very easy if I can.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To select any `input` elements that aren't descendants of a `form` element you can use,

```
$('input:not(form input)')
```

***[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/fwzMY/)***

**[Reference](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)**

> All selectors are accepted inside
>   :not(), for example: :not(div a) and
>   :not(div,a).

Comment: WOW! Thanks for solution and nice site suggestion!

Comment: No problem, yeah jsfiddle.net is great for quickly testing code.

Comment: What if the form is 'this' form, how do you do $('input:not(this input)')

Answer (score 1):

You can use filter to remove elements that are within a form element. For example:

```
$('input').filter(function() {
    return $(this).closest('form').size() === 0;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe..
Some combo of not and child selectors?
$("input:not(#myForm > input)")

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input').not('form input')
```

should get the input elements that don't have form as an ancestor

Answer (score 0):

It will be a bit expensive but one way to do this will be

```
$("input").filter(function(i,e){
return $(this).closest("form selector goes here").length==0;
});
```

this will return only those input elements which do not have the "form selector" as their ancestor.